# How do I handle variable screen sizes when dealing with Fixed Size WinForms? C#

Tags: c#, winforms

So far I have a form maybe 900 x 900 in size and I just realized that this would probably clip with the taskbar of some monitor sizes. How do i deal with this if my Window is fixed? (It is fixed because my elements are exactly where I want them to be (I.e.: Panels buttons and many other things would leave a blank space if size is adjustable.

Comment: Fixed size forms makes sense for small dialogs, for more complex forms you don't want them to have a fixed size. Maybe you as a developer find this to be good solution, but would you as a user ? Monitor size, resolution and DPI are all factors that makes this a bad idea, make use of panels, anchor-property, dock-property etc. to make your form responsive

Comment: I don't think WinForms has a good solution for this problem. The issue is compounded by the "make fonts bigger" feature in the display settings. You pretty much need to code to the least common denominator. I develop our local apps with 125% and size forms to our typical screen. (TDull - the "small dialogs" often fail when desktop font size is increased - typically the buttons are force off the bottom of the dialog.) One option is to plan on providing scrollable forms.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the width and Height dynamically via codebehind... something like this:

```
int screenWidth = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
int screenHeight = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;

if(screenWidth < 900)
{
    this.Width = 800;
}
else if(screenHeight < 900)
{
    this.Height = 800;
}
```